# Trying to declare a variable of a table type, and print its value in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Below syntax I have used.

```
 declare
      v_data emp_tab ;
    BEGIN
      select * into v_data from emp_tab where emp_id= 121 limit 1;
      raise notice 'Value: %', v_data.emp_info;
    END;
```

which is throwing an error. "syntax error at or near emp_tab"
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
do $$
    declare
    v_data emp_tab ;
    BEGIN
        select * into v_data from emp_tab where emp_id= 121 limit 1;
        raise notice 'Value: %', v_data.emp_info;
    END;
$$ language plpgsql
```